# Capture size of an ImageView (Image Inside) after loading Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a RecyclerView that is not a list of images that are loaded not Glide (version 3.7.0), in which case I use three buttons (large, medium and small) that change the contents of RecyclerView (updating as images). With this some loaded images are smaller than others (but this within an established pattern in each of the buttons). I need to know the exact moment in an image loaded after the button action for the component and so I can get its size (in the case of an image inside the ImageView component).